# Сортировка div элементов

Tags: javascript, html, сортировка

Подскажите пожалуйста, как отсортировать родительские элементы `.user` по алфавиту относительно содержимого в дочерних элементах `.user__user-name`.

**1:** Cортировка в редакторе кода, что бы в ручную не менять местами.

**2:** Сортировка на сайте.

```css
.user-list__user {
  background: #325;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #287;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Test</title>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
<main class="main">
 <div class="user-list">
  <div class="user user-list__user">
   <span class="user__user-name">Вася</span>
   <span class="user__user-age">45<span>
  </div>
  <div class="user user-list__user">
   <span class="user__user-name">Андрей</span>
   <span class="user__user-age">18</span>
  </div>
  <div class="user user-list__user">
   <span class="user__user-name">Сережа</span>
   <span class="user__user-age">12</span>
  </div>
  <div class="user user-list__user">
   <span class="user__user-name">Маша</span>
   <span class="user__user-age">34</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</main>
<script src="js/main.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(window).load(function () {
    var c = jQuery.makeArray($("#user-list >"));
    c.sort(function (a, b) {
        a = $(a).text();
        b = $(b).text();
       return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0
    });
    $(c).appendTo("#user-list")
});
```

```css
.user-list__user {
  background: #325;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #287;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user-list" id="user-list">
  <div class="user user-list__user">
   <span class="user__user-name">Вася</span>
   <span class="user__user-age">45<span>
  </div>
  <div class="user user-list__user">
   <span class="user__user-name">Андрей</span>
   <span class="user__user-age">18</span>
  </div>
  <div class="user user-list__user">
   <span class="user__user-name">Сережа</span>
   <span class="user__user-age">12</span>
  </div>
  <div class="user user-list__user">
   <span class="user__user-name">Маша</span>
   <span class="user__user-age">34</span>
  </div>
 </div>
```