# Как при верстки сортировать div элементы?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, сортировка

Есть страница со списком актеров на примере [этой](https://uznayvse.ru/znamenitosti/aktery-kino-gollivud/). Допустим я сверстал все элементы, но последовательность нарушена. Как отсортировать элементы в редакторе по имени актеров, ибо в ручную делать - мрак. Подскажите как поступают при верстки сайтов в таких случая?

```css
.user-list__user {
  background: #325;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #287;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Test</title>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
<main class="main">
 <div class="user-list">
  <div class="user user-list__user">
   <span class="user__user-name">Вася</span>
   <span class="user__user-age">45<span>
  </div>
  <div class="user user-list__user">
   <span class="user__user-name">Андрей</span>
   <span class="user__user-age">18</span>
  </div>
  <div class="user user-list__user">
   <span class="user__user-name">Сережа</span>
   <span class="user__user-age">12</span>
  </div>
  <div class="user user-list__user">
   <span class="user__user-name">Маша</span>
   <span class="user__user-age">34</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</main>
<script src="js/main.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ну я бы отсортировал имена актёров, потом написал бы крохотный скрипт и получил бы разметку.

Comment: @Hipster можете продемонстрировать пример пожалуйста?

Comment: Страница статичная? Или имена актеров поднимаются из базы?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov статичная. Все элементы я верстаю сам, а не подгружаю, но если вам не сложно, можете привести 2 примера на будущие)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну можно тупо отсортировать скриптом при выводе

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  (function() {
    var users = $('div.user');
    var cmp = function(left, right) {
      if (left < right)
        return -1;
      if (left == right)
        return 0;
      return 1;
    }
    users.sort(function(left, right) {
      var res = cmp(
        $('.user__user-name', left).text(),
        $('.user__user-name', right).text()
      );
      if (res === 0) {
        res = cmp(
          parseInt($('.user__user-age', left).text()),
          parseInt($('.user__user-age', right).text())
        );
      }
      return res;
    });
    var parent = users.parent();
    users.detach().appendTo(parent).show();
  })();
});
```

```css
.user-list__user {
  background: #325;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #287;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="user-list">
      <div class="user user-list__user">
        <span class="user__user-name">Вася</span>
        <span class="user__user-age">45</span>
      </div>
      <div class="user user-list__user">
        <span class="user__user-name">Андрей</span>
        <span class="user__user-age">18</span>
      </div>
      <div class="user user-list__user">
        <span class="user__user-name">Сережа</span>
        <span class="user__user-age">12</span>
      </div>
      <div class="user user-list__user">
        <span class="user__user-name">Маша</span>
        <span class="user__user-age">34</span>
      </div>
      <div class="user user-list__user">
        <span class="user__user-name">Маша</span>
        <span class="user__user-age">5</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Или отделить мух от котлет. В смысле данные от отображения

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  (function() {
    var users = [
      {name: "Вася", age: 45},
      {name: "Андрей", age: 18},
      {name: "Сережа", age: 12},
      {name: "Маша", age: 34},
      {name: "Маша", age: 5}
    ];
    var cmp = function(left, right) {
      if (left < right)
        return -1;
      if (left == right)
        return 0;
      return 1;
    }
    users.sort(function(left, right) {
      var res = cmp(left.name, right.name);
      if (res === 0)
        res = cmp(left.age, right.age);
      return res;
    });
    var template = $('div.user');
    var parent = template.parent();
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      $('.user__user-name', template).text(users[i].name);
      $('.user__user-age', template).text(users[i].age);
      template = template.appendTo(parent).clone();
    };
  })();
});
```

```css
.user-list__user {
  background: #325;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #287;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="user-list">
      <div class="user user-list__user">
        <span class="user__user-name"></span>
        <span class="user__user-age"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: в этом мне уже [помогли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/761583/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-div-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), но вот как это делать в редакторе я не знаю. Можно поломать голову и написать скрип, который впитает html и выведет отсортированный код, но у меня даже такой практики не было

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный Что мешает запустить мой скрипт, а потом тупо скопировать DOM дерево из браузера?

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста как работает  $('.user__user-name', left).text(). Я понимаю что left, это  $(".user")[i++] или что бы было проще: _$('.user__user-name', $(".user")[0]);_. Читая [про селекторы](http://anton.shevchuk.name/javascript/jquery-for-beginners-selectors/) `jquery` я не нашел пример с передачей двух аргументов и как они между собой взаимодействую.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный [плохо искали](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) Второй аргумент это контекст. Относительно какого элемента делать выборку. Если он не указан, то ищется от корня документа. А если указан, то от этого элемента